# Is there any way to bypass authentication on an Azure App

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have an Azure function App which I have authenticated from Azure AD. Now every function of my function app require credentials to execute. However, for few functions I want to execute without authentication or providing credentials.

Is there any way by which I can enable authentication for few Azure functions in an App and for others no authentication is required?

Answer (score 1):

In FunctionApps, authentication is done at the `AppService` level, so it applies to every function within your `FunctionApp`.
If you want some of your functions to require AAD (Azure Active Directory) authentication, and others not, you can either split the functions that do not require authentication into their own functionapp without AAD (turned off), and leave the others as is.

Otherwise, you can implement authentication yourself via code using the libraries available from Microsoft. 
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries). If you're using Javascript, here the SDKs:

[MSAL for Javascript](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)
[ADAL for Javascript](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)

Now, I usually recommend for all API requests to be authenticated for production environments, so keep that in mind.